# How Ruby's authlogic is compared to Python's repoze.what/who library?

Tags: python, ruby, authentication, authlogic, repoze.who

I am trying to understand architecture of authlogic and repoze.what/who libraries but I could get the first level architectural definition. repoze packages seems to use the zope modules at some level..

Are there any equivalent or easier authentication framework like authlogic available in python? (I do not use Django.. I use Pylons)

Anyone has more insight into these libraries?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a quick look at authlogic's homepage, I would say it can be compared to repoze.who because they both handle *authentication*. On the other hand, repoze.what handles *authorization*. For more information, you may want to see this:
http://gustavonarea.net/blog/posts/repoze-auth/

HTH.

PS: Neither repoze.who or repoze.what use Zope ([it's the wider Repoze project that is related to Zope](http://docs.repoze.org/hacking/overview.html)). repoze.who uses zope.interface, but that's a Zope-independent library which was born within the Zope project.